# Which Active Directory Exchange class has the mailNickName?

Tags: active-directory, powerquery

I am using Power M query in Excel to pull AD user attributes but I cannot find the mailNickName attribute.  I know how to do it using LDAP query or Powershell but don’t know which AD class this attribute is in?  Would appreciate the name of the AD Exchange Class that contains this attribute.